# Unable to display variable values

Tags: debugging, xcode5, debug-symbols

Environment: Xcode Version 5.0.1 (5A2034a)

Scenario:
   1) I've create a simple Apple-supplied iOS project template. 
   2) I create a local string value with an initial value; plus a local integer variable with value. 
   3) I did a debug 'po' & 'p' for the object and integer.

[image: Simple method with debug access to local variables]

Xcode's debugger apparently doesn't see these values.

The following are a couple of snippets of the debugger's environment:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the debugger's symbol-generator is ON and the optimization is set to NO (zero).

---

1) Here's another example.

Note: NSLog() does work. 
Notice the 'Turkey' for 'testString' value.  **Why this value?**

'Turkey' was used in ANOTHER project and has no relevance to this one sample project.

It appears that I'm getting variable bleed from some xcode environment peculiar to Xcode 5;
...not found/experienced in Xcode 4.

Okay, this is weird.   I've tried the NSLog() and got the values displayed.  Then just for kicks I did a 'po' again and got the correct value.

However I still have the 'Turkey' value:
[image]

---

2) Here's a second example. 
Starting with a new application from the Apple-supplied view template: 
[image]

This time, the NSLog() works but again, can't get the 'po' value.

I still haven't figured out the pattern here.

What else can I do?

**How can I get my debugger 'po' & 'p' commands to show data?**

 
Or... why am I'm getting inconsistent debugger behavior (Xcode5 appears to work okay; re 'NSLog()')?

Comment: I realize you've turned off optimizations, but just for fun, does it work the way you expect if you use the variables before exiting?  Try `NSLog(@"%@ - %@", myString, @(x));` before the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this recurrent problem so I tried logging via a different account to find the problem disappeared.

So there's something wrong with my Xcode account; specifically:

[image]

So I emptied the Xcode folder found under ~/Library/Developer and restarted Xcode.
Apparently the problem(s) is/are solved.